# Exchanging classes between two divs when clickin on one of them

Tags: jquery

I have this code below. When I run the app and I click on "bar", the message `The not 'current' div has been clicked` is shown. Then if I click on "foo", the message is not shown. I expected the message was shown, since I have exchanged the class `current` between the two `divs`.

```
<div class="current">foo</div>
<div>bar</div>

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('div').not('.current').on('click', function(){
        alert("The not 'current' div has been clicked.")
        var aux = $(this);
        $('div').removeClass('current');
        aux.addClass('current');
    });
});
```

Comment: right after document was loaded, you assigned a click listener to all elements that don't have class `current`. The first div having the class is hence not in the collection and will never have the listener.

Comment: @PetrČihula ok, thanks, I didn't know that I was "assigning" permantely, is there any way to do this without "assinging"?

Comment: If by "without assigning" you mean "not repeatedly assigning each time the class is changed" there's a solution using `.live()` (jQuery < 1.7) for every `div:not(.current)` or just simple `.on()` (>= 1.7) applied up on the document object with the same child selector. See http://jsfiddle.net/MMjx4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On DOM ready, you have assigned the click event only for the div not having the class `current`. Hence, the code doesn't work. You need to assign the click events to all the div's and check for the class inside it like:

```
$('div').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.className === 'current') return;
    console.log("The not 'current' div has been clicked.")
    var $aux = $(this);
    $('div').removeClass('current');
    $aux.addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: ok, thanks, is there any way to do what I want without aissinging an event handler?

Comment: I don't think that's possible without aissinging any event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You only add the click event to the "not current" element, and when you switch classes one of the elements still has no click event. Instead you can do:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('div').on('click', function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("current")){
            return;
        }

        alert("The not 'current' div has been clicked.")
        var aux = $(this);
        $('div').removeClass('current');
        aux.addClass('current');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('div').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('current')) return;

        alert("The not 'current' div has been clicked.")
        var aux = $(this);
        $('div').removeClass('current');
        aux.addClass('current');
    });
});
```

Check the class inside the callback ;)

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5hFv4/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is on clicking of a div which does not have a `.current` class would get the click event and swap the `.current` class, as you are manipulating dom with the jQuery and swapping the class, it does not get the applied new class, it takes the element which was loaded when page was ready, so you can delegate the event to the `document` and you would get what you want:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div:not(.current)', function () {
  alert("The not 'current' div has been clicked.");
  var aux = $(this);
  $('div').removeClass('current');
  aux.addClass('current');
});
```

[**Tryout this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RZ4bk/)

Comment: ok, thanks, is there any way to do what I want without aissinging an event handler?